# EITHER Compare Two Sheets for Differences OR detect changes on a sheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

A function is creating sheets (by duplicating a sheet from a template), filling data on the sheets (or not) and then adding the sheet to the worksheet.

I would like to skip sheets where there is no change... which due to the complexity of the data being updated would be to either compare the sheet with it's template OR to know if it has changes.

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify("somefile.xls");
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("somefile.xls");
$sourceSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet = $sourceSheet->copy();
//many "potential" changes to the cells
if ($sheet == $sourceSheet) 
    //do action when same
else
    //do action when different
```

the "if ($sheet == $sourceSheet) " is what would be ideal, but I'm asking for what is the best way to do this.

Which is practical and best practice - e.g. I think programmatically comparing every cell one by one is going to be very expensive - so I'm hoping there is a function for one of the methods I can use.

**UPDATE** - I've added code to indicate where "sheet" comes from

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the actual contents, what about hashing the file and checking the result hash via md5_file?

For example

```
if(md5_file($file1) == md5_file($file2)){
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Alternatively, if you aren't using a real file you can just use `md5()` on the string for the sheet.

Comment: sorry, but no - I said to compare a "sheet", not a "worksheet file"

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is a _sheet_?

Comment: Sorry if I've confused things.. I've updated the above to give more context.  It is important that there are alot of these so I'm not looking to wirte and then read from the disk as that would be expensive... both sheets are in memory and that must be the way they are compared... well I assume so... but I suppose I'm the one asking here not teelling!

Comment: I don't really understand the code. If `$sheet` is equal to `$sourceSheet->copy();` and `$sourceSheet` is equal to `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();` then surely `$sheet` will always equal `$sourceSheet`, no?